# When is the right time to turn on phase wires A, B and C in a sensored BLDC motor to make it rotate?

Tags: arduino, current, brushless-dc-motor, hall-effect

I just bought a sensored bldc motor and I built an esc for it. Here is [the schematic](http://electronoobs.com/images/Circuitos/tut_19/sch_2.png)

When I power everything on I can hear the motor trying to turn, but it keeps getting stuck and it won't budge. I am assuming this is because i'm not allowing current to flow to the right phase at the right time.

I know which phase wire corresponds to which hall sensor because they have the same colored wires, but how do you know when to turn the phase wire on at the right time? Is it when hall SensorA reads a high value I need to turn on Phase wire A? Or am I supposed to turn Phase wire A on when sensorB / sensorC reads a high value?

Here is [the motor that I bought](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08L5WDTSZ) if that helps you out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Power one phase, at low current so the motor doesn't overheat, and the torque is not excessive.

Forcibly rotate the shaft, while observing the outputs of the position sensors, and either measuring the torque (if you can), or noting the positions of zero torque, and the angles of positive and negative torque. Draw a graph of those two versus angle.

It should now be apparent from the graph at what sensed angles you should apply which drive phases. Remember you have done this at DC. You may need to advance the timing when rotating to allow for sensor response time, and current lagging voltage in the drive phases.

Comment: How much current / voltage do you think I need to feel the torque? The motor is rated up to 50 volts and when I apply 4 volts i'm getting about 2 amps of current. Is that enough?

Comment: that worked for me THANK YOU so much man. Been stuck on this problem the past week :( should have asked sooner.